# Macro VBA : What is wrong with my code ? Row delete

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete the entire row if any cell in column A is blank.

Also this code should run on two specific sheets only (i.e. "ATM SLA Availability Report" & "Incident Report") within the same workbook.

Below is my code. It gives me Run-Time error 9 when I run it.

```
Sub test()
    Worksheets("ATM SLA Availability Report").Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
    Worksheets("Incident Report").Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Run-Time error 9` indicates "Out of Range" meaning that you're trying to reference something that doesn't exist within the worksheet (or workbook), likely from one of your sheet names spelled incorrectly.

I don't see anything wrong with your code, I've tested it myself and it works fine for me. You can check further at which line the code is giving the error by clicking "Debug" when the error pops up.

Comment: You are right. There was a space at the end of the sheet name.Worked now

Thank you